# error while installing gmp (frama-c prerequisite) on mac os catalina using opam on terminal

Tags: macos-catalina, frama-c, opam

I ran these commands to install Frama-C as said on http://frama-c.com/install-sulfur-20171101.html#installing-frama-c-on-mac-os-x:

> 1. `brew install autoconf opam`
>
> Do not forget to `opam init` and `eval $(opam config env)` for a proper OPAM installation (if not already done before on your machine).
>
> 2. `brew install gmp gtk+ gtksourceview libgnomecanvas`
> 3. `brew install graphviz`
>
>    `opam install altgr-ergo why3`

I encountered an error after the 3rd command (of course there are 2 more commands to install frama-c completely, but the same error is showing up after the last command too).

```
ERROR while compiling conf-gmp.1

test.c:7:2: error: implicit declaration of function '__gmp_init' is invalid in C99 [-Werror,-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
         __gmp_init();
```

Answer (score 3):

Your issue is related to opam and the `conf-gmp` (version 1) package in particular, which is *used* by Frama-C, but not caused by it.

If you do `opam update` and then `opam install conf-gmp.2`, you should be able to install the package without errors.

Otherwise, if you have control over whatever is adding `-Werror` to your `CFLAGS` environment variable, you can try removing it and reinstalling the packages.

#### Long explanation

It is likely that your `CFLAGS` environment variable contains `-Werror` or some similar setting which is causing the warning emitted by `conf-gmp` during its compilation to become an error.

The `conf-gmp.1` package indeed does emit a warning when compiled, but in standard settings, the warning is simply ignored by opam and everything works. In your system, the warning became an error, and prevented the other packages from being installed.

A new version of `conf-gmp` was posted after the issue was noticed due to this question. Running `opam update` and then `opam install conf-gmp.2` should get this new version and hopefully avoid any warnings. Note that having `-Werrors` in `CFLAGS` may trigger some issues in other packages, however. For instance, in my configuration, it is impossible to install `lablgtk` with `-Werror`, since its compilation inevitably raises several warnings. It might be necessary to add `CFLAGS=-Wno-error` or similar to ensure lablgtk will be compiled. Otherwise, you may have to compile Frama-C from source (lablgtk is optional in this case).